# Generate a Matrix with Column Sum Constraint in R

Tags: r, matrix

For example, I can easily specify an arbitrary matrix like

```
x <- matrix(c(10,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,
              10,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,
              10,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,
              10,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25),
              nrow = 4, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
```

But in an optimization problem, I am required to use a matrix `x` under constraints `max(colSums(x)) <= 1`. How can I generate such a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I will put my comment into an answer.

```
x <- matrix(c(10,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,
              10,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,
              10,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,
              10,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25),
              nrow = 4, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
alpha <- colSums(x) + runif(ncol(x), 0, abs(mean(x)))
y <- t(t(x) / alpha)

> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   10 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
[2,]   10 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
[3,]   10 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
[4,]   10 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
> y
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0.2397915 0.1814021 0.09312788 0.09021147 0.1116572 0.1147005
[2,] 0.2397915 0.1814021 0.09312788 0.09021147 0.1116572 0.1147005
[3,] 0.2397915 0.1814021 0.09312788 0.09021147 0.1116572 0.1147005
[4,] 0.2397915 0.1814021 0.09312788 0.09021147 0.1116572 0.1147005

> alpha  ## random scaling factor
[1] 41.702890  1.378154  2.684481  2.771266  2.238996  2.179589

> colSums(y)
[1] 0.9591661 0.7256085 0.3725115 0.3608459 0.4466288 0.4588021
```

I did not set seed. So when you run, the result will be different.

---

**Follow-up**

> Perfect thanks a lot. Just one additional comment. With this method, can I control specific column sum to be <=1, i.e, what if I don't want the constraint for the first column but for others!

You can manually set `alpha[1]` to be 1, so that essentially no scaling is done.

```
alpha <- colSums(x) + runif(0, abs(mean(x)), ncol(x))
alpha[1] <- 1
```

Then proceed. If you want 3rd column not affected as well, do

```
alpha[c(1,3)] <- 1
```

---

**random seed**

Compare:

```
runif(4)
## [1] 0.1300864 0.5689224 0.5594464 0.8778068
runif(4)
## [1] 0.3320244 0.5838847 0.0466045 0.2594867
```

But if we set seed:

```
set.seed(0); runif(4)
## [1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534
set.seed(0); runif(4)
## [1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534
```

Without using seed, random numbers are not reproducible. I did not put `set.seed(0)` before `alpha`, so when you run the code, you will see different `alpha`, `y`.

The seed can be any integers, not necessarily 0. For example, both -2016 and 2016 works. But for different seed, you get different set of random numbers. However, whenever you use the same seed, the random numbers are the same.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this.. I am new to R. what do you mean by "did not seed"?

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot. Just one additional comment. With this method, can I control specific column sum to be <=1, i.e, what if I don't want the constraint for the first column but for others!

Comment: Thnks.. Interesting. It works!!  I just wonder how would "optim()" react to this? I pass the "x" matrix as variables to the Optim, and then based on the suggestion, we are again changing the matrix values. I have a feeling there will be mismatch. I will debug and try.

Comment: I like your suggestion in this scenario. I will keep it as it is. It may benefit others.  I shall post another question explaining the issue. Cheers!